# Thematic Map from a STATCAN Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, mapinfo, thematic-map

I want to create a thematic map of my data. I downloaded a shapefile from Statistics Canada website displaying the various agricultural regions. I have data in Excel

How do I add this data and match it each polygon?

I've been reading the manual and seem to be getting more confused.

I am using Mapinfo Pro v8.5

Comment: Which manual have you been reading, what software are you using.

Comment: apologies, I am using Mapinfo Pro v8.5

Comment: Import your excel data and then do an SQL join on a common ID field. That is the standard way of joining up linked data from 2 or more data sources in MapInfo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing much about MapInfo, I would point you to the Census Agricultural Regions:

http://www.statcan.gc.ca/pub/92-174-x/92-174-x2007000-eng.htm

From there, you can see the regions on your map, and exploring the data, you'll find there are various ID's for the different polygons: CARuid, PRuid, AGuid

I would assume the data your trying to map has one of those ID's in the spreadsheet / table.

You need to figure out how in MapInfo you can link your table to one of the ID's mentioned above in order to then map the values from the table at the agricultural region above.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I used the logic and was able to figure it out! thanks again

Comment: @coolintake oh great! Please mark that as your answer if you could. Thanks!!!